# Handling both EntityRepository and QueryBuilder for PagerBundle in Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm, query-builder

The [PagerBundle](https://github.com/makerlabs/PagerBundle) is a very useful bundle for handling pagination in Symfony2. However, it provides 
the adapter [DoctrineOrmAdapter](https://github.com/makerlabs/PagerBundle/blob/master/Adapter/DoctrineOrmAdapter.php) for Doctrine2 based on `QueryBuilder`.

Then, one should create a specific query with the `QueryBuilder` inside each controller. This approach will bring to the need of defining *ad hoc* functions that can be used inside the controllers, as well as possible problem when the table schema change. In fact, the correct approach is to use the user-defined `EntityRepository`, which contains all the useful queries for the Doctrine Entity.

Each call to the `EntityRepository` should return the result of a query, not a `Query` object or a `QueryBuilder` object. 
So, how do you suggest to handle this problem?

PS: Please, don't answer that I can return a QueryBuilder by the functions of the entity repository. It is trivial!

Comment: In my opinion this behaviour is intended by the pager bundle. I'd recommend building your own custom paginator.

But also, there is a way to use repository a call.

$queryBuilder->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Entity')->findByWhatsoEver().

Where the "getRepository" function would hand you your custom EntityRepository you set in your Entity.